# PHP doesn't read the line for no reason

Tags: php, slim

I implement a rest API based on slim, one of the function is to return true if email have been registered:

```
public function emailValidation($request, $response){
    $email = $request->getParam('email');
    $check = false;

    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?";

    $conn = $this->container->db;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows){
        $check = true;
    }

    return $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')->write(json_encode($check));
}
```

When I test it on RESTclient, it does work and return true when email is been used, however when I post the request from my slim project it always fetches false for no reason. I think the problem is it never reach to the if statement instead it skipped it and return the response with the $check=false.

Does anyone know how to fix this??

EDIT:
this is the postSignUp function

```
public function postSignUp($request, $response) {

        //catch all field been passed and called validate method for validation
        //rules and exceptions could be change via Validation\Exceptions or Rules
        $validation = $this->container->validator->validate($request, [
            'email' => v::noWhiteSpace()->notEmpty()->email()->EmailValidation(),
            'username' => v::notEmpty(),
            'password' => v::noWhiteSpace()->notEmpty(),
        ]);

        if ($validation->failed()){
           return $response->withRedirect($this->container->router->pathFor('auth.signup'));
        }

        $email = $request->getParam('email');
        $username = $request->getParam('username');
        $password = $request->getParam('password');

        $postData = http_build_query(
            array(
                'email' => $email,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password
            )
        );

        $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $postData,
            ),
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
            )
        );
        //set up request content
        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        //sending out web request
        $result = file_get_contents('https://localhost/restapi/public/user/add', false, $context);

        if ($result){
            //Flash message announce information
            $this->container->flash->addMessage('info', 'Sign Up has been successful.');

            //$this->container->auth->attempt($email, $request->getParam('password'));

            return $response->withRedirect($this->container->router->pathFor('auth.login'));
        }
    }
```

this is the validation rules php:

```
namespace App\Validation\Rules;

use Respect\Validation\Rules\AbstractRule;

class EmailValidation extends AbstractRule {

    public function validate($input){
        //will return true when email has already exist in database
        $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $input,
            ),
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
            )
        );
        //set up request content
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        //sending out web request
        $contents = file_get_contents('https://localhost/restapi/public/user/validate', false, $context);
        $result = json_decode($contents);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggested adding echo statements at various points to verify that variables contain what you expect them to at various points.

Comment: @Adam you're wrong, $stmt->num_rows is definitely a thing. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: I have done many times to test it, in Restclient it does reach to the if statement and change $check to true however when I called API in my project it never reach to that part

Comment: You need to bind_result, then execute(). It'll then give you a num_rows of true

Comment: @clearshot66 That's not necessary, `store_result()` is enough.

Comment: "when I called API in my project"  You should probably show the code that does that

Comment: PHP doesn't skip statements by itself.

Comment: The problem is most likely that you're not sending the email properly when you call the API. What does `var_dump($email)` show?

Comment: @Barmar it shows the email that I post in the form